# User is duplicated when calling Reply

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I'm trying to make a simple forum using MVC and I can't figure out why the user that is posting the reply is getting duplicated.

Here is the Reply Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Reply(string Title, string Content,int ReplyTo)
{
    Post masterPost = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PostID == ReplyTo);
    Post post = new Post();
    post.PostID = 0;
    post.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    post.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
    post.ReplyTo = masterPost;
    post.Forum = db.Forums.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.ForumID == masterPost.Forum.ForumID);
    post.User = (User)Session["User"];
    post.Title = Title;
    post.Content = Content;

    //if (ModelState.IsValid)
    //{
        db.Posts.Add(post);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("View", "Posts", new { id = ReplyTo });
    //}
    return View(post);
}
```

This is the Post entity:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public virtual Forum Forum { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Post ReplyTo { get; set; }
}
```

This is the User entity:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisteredOn { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever the ReplyTo action is called it creates the Post but it also duplicates the User that is stored in the session (with a different UserID).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you don't state it, it looks like you use Entity Framework.

If so, the culprit is probably this line

```
post.User = (User)Session["User"];
```

The "User" you store in session is now disconnected from Entity Framework, so EF assumes it is a brand-new user.

There are several ways to solve this.  The one I prefer is to also add a UserId property to your Post class and use that

```
public class Post
{
    // Stuff
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Then do:

```
post.UserId = ((User)Session["User"]).Id;
```

Entity Framework uses a convention to understand that you want to link that user to that post.

Comment: Yes. That was exactly the solution I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So when you say "it also duplicates the User", I conclude what you mean is that you get a duplicate User type in the DB after the db.SaveChanges.

Given that as my presumption, then I would speculate that the User stored in Session["Usser"] does not have an existing UserID property set, AND/OR your EF model does not have the Post to User multiplicity association set. Ordinarily, I would expect to see UserId property in Post, and your sample above does not show this.

Check your model to make sure you have the assocation set between User and Post, and that there's a foreign key property linking Post to User. The Post object requires a foreign key referencing UserId.

Take a [look at Step 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) in this example from Microsoft.